# Can you force a console app to look like a gui app?

Tags: c++, user-interface, console

I've been weighing the pro's/con's of making a gui app, and I've decided a console app is much more powerful for my calculator, especialy since it does different things like foil, quadratic equations, etc. So my question is make the console look like a gui based app?

Comment: What is the point of trying to make a console app look like a gui app instead of making a gui app?

Comment: Well, I can't exactly figure out how to go about implementing features such as quadratic equation solving, foil solving, etc inside of a gui, it's so much easier  to have the user input the values themselves & then solve it for them. But, of course a console app is kinda ugly, so i'd like to mask it as much as possible to appear like a gui app. Also, to be completely honest, I'm not entirely sure I could even create a gui app, I'm not the most skilled coder.

Comment: Last I heard you could do input in gui apps.

Comment: GIven an appropriate IDE with a form designer, GUI apps are quite easy to develop.  The actual  code for solving the equations would be the same.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses?

Comment: Hmm What would you recommend I use Mr James?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on exactly what you mean by "console." If you're talking about Windows console windows, then the answer is "maybe." Some Windows installations can emulate VGA/EGA graphics within a console window, making them able to play old games for DOS.

Your mission would be to implement every GUI widget you need, such as clickable buttons, text-entry fields, etc. in terms of simple graphics primitives for drawing lines and rectangles. Then you have to write code that figures out where the mouse is and draws the mouse pointer in the right spot. You'd also have to write code to make the cursor blink, to make the arrow keys move the cursor, and to make it possible to select characters in a text entry box and copy, cut, and paste them.

When you got done, you'd have a program that works on some people's computers, but not on others. On some Windows installations, the console windows can't do graphics or go fullscreen. Your app wouldn't work at all on those systems, although you could write a fullscreen Windows app using a 2D game library such as SDL or Allegro instead of writing a console app, which would bring you back to the previous paragraph.

As you might have guessed by now, rolling your own GUI would be a whole lot more work than writing a Windows GUI program in which the buttons, text fields, etc are already implemented for you, the cursor already blinks, the mouse already clicks, etc.

Also, the code that does the actual calculations should be totally separate
from the code that gets the input from the user and puts the answers on the screen, so that code shouldn't factor into whether you want to write a GUI or a console app. They shouldn't even be in the same `.cpp` file as the I/O routines.

Now, some programmers use the term "console" to refer to xterm windows on Linux. These are not the same thing at all, and cannot draw graphics (and "console" is the wrong name for them to boot). But sometimes you see menus and stuff within them, "drawn" with colored text. Usually, these are drawn and managed using the external `dialog` shell command.

Comment: Ahh I see. I decided to go the gui route via windows forms (which means I'm now having to do c#), and I've ran into an issue with my foil button. 
here's the code:

 double x1, x2, y1, y2,sum,sum2,sum3,sum4;
 x1 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
 y1 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
 x2 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
 y2 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
 sum = x1 * y1;
 sum2 = x2 * y1;
 sum3 = x2 * y1;
 sum4 = x2 * y2;
 textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(sum,sum2,sum3 ,sum4);

I can't figure out how to display the 4 sums in 1 textbox.

Comment: I don't do C#, so I can't be of much help. But glimpsing at the documentation, it looks like System::Convert::ToString can only convert 1 number at a time. The solution involves converting them with separate calls to ToString and then appending the 4 strings together, with spaces in between. In C++ I'd use _snprintf(final_string, LENGTH, "%f %f %f %f", sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4) to do the conversion.